# what is reward behavior?

Tags: expressions

> There is evidence that sugar is particularly harmful for the
>   adolescent brain, which is especially responsive to **rewarding
>   behaviors**. Unsurprisingly, eating tasty foods high in sugar, salt or
>   fat is hard to resist. But research has shown that male rats that
>   drank sugar water during adolescence showed less motivation and
>   pursued rewards as adults, behaviors that signify depression and other
>   mood disorders.

What does rewarding behavior mean here?

Comment: two ideas compound for me:

Comment: With phrase "responsive to rewarding behavior", different ideas compound for me: 1. like rewards; and 2. keep asking, or keep looking for rewards persistently. Unfortunately, the support sentences in this paragraph confuses me, especially then one about rats. As i guess, rat does little but likes to get rewarded and keeps looking for it as they grow into adulthood. Naturally, a reward (sugary water in our case) is not always available, thus making rat feel depressed or stressed.

Answer (score 1):

Rewarding behavior means that young people are often given sugar or sweets as a reward for good behavior.

It is not recommended, as  during an experiment, rats were seen to be less motivated after consuming sugar.
So the person's body could also be less motivated to continue such behavior in the future.

Comment: rat pursuing for reward means it keeps looking for reward, right?

Comment: @khongor yes, it means it kept looking for the reward